# What would happen to the universe if gravity became slightly stronger?

Tags: gravity, universe

Almost the same as my [other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2870/24) but it isn't about how the universe would form.

What would happen if to the universe if someone changed the strength of gravity by say 2%?

Comment: So this is talking about changing the gravitational strength in an already existing universe? How rapidly does it change?

Comment: @TimB Immediately in our universe

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: @Vincent This one is about what would happen if it changed **now**, the other's about the formation of the universe.

Comment: Ummm....2% more black holes?

Comment: Should this question have the science-based tag?

Comment: @kingledion [See my earlier comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/what-would-happen-to-the-universe-if-gravity-became-slightly-stronger?noredirect=1#comment5861_2971)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything would become slightly heavier. 2% isn't enough to make huge changes, although birds would find it harder to fly. Buildings would be slightly weaker and fall more easily. Trips and falls would become slightly more dangerous, etc. Most buildings, supports, etc we make have far more than 2% redundancy so they would not start collapsing as a result of this change.

This would have interesting effects on the orbit of planets though. Suddenly planets are not moving fast enough to maintain their current orbit, that will cause them to fall in towards the sun until they gain enough speed and settle into a new orbit. The new orbit would almost certainly be both more eccentric than the previous one and shorter, the length of the year would change.

Equally the moon would shift into an eccentric orbit, and tides would grow stronger. The faster orbit of the moon would also break the tidal lock, causing it to no longer always point one face towards the earth. Over time that would correct but the correction would not be instant.

Comment: Your assumptions are valid only if gravity suddenly increased. If it was 2% from the very beginning (Big Bang), your answer is invalid and @John Meacham answer has better explanation of the consequences.

Comment: @PeterMasiar yes. I asked that specific question in the comments on the question though...

Answer (score 14):

Things would be *extremely* bad, for large values of extreme.

Stars are a balancing act of external radiation pressure exactly counteracting the gravitational attractive force. By increasing gravity stars suddenly have 2% more gravitational potential energy they need to shed to regain equilibrium. How much energy is that? The gravitational potential energy of the Sun is 10<sup>41</sup> Joules. Or roughly the same energy as would be released if the *entire Earth* were to be anhiliated with anti-matter. 2% of that is huge and it suddenly appears out of nowhere. So, very quickly the Sun has to shed about 10,000 times its yearly energy output. Life is certainly not going to survive that, but this happens for every star in the galaxy. Many, many will jumpstart to a higher order of fusion at the massive sudden increase in pressure and temperature, if they start iron-burning, you are in trouble.

Expect every supergiant to go supernova concurrently and many lesser stars to flare with the energy output comparable to a nova, any life that survives the semi-nova/flare of the Sun will be wiped out by the bombardment of gamma rays that will be bathing the Earth for the next few thousand years.

Every black hole will get a bit bigger all of a sudden as escape velocity increases, eating part of its accretion disk. Hard to say what effect this would have actually, but sounds like it may cause trouble.

Depending on exactly how the increase in gravity is carried out, even more esoteric things might happen. It is a well known unsolved problem in physics that the gravitational mass and inertial mass of matter are independent yet appear to always be exactly the same. As in, there are no laws that say they should be the same nor does it naturally arise from any currently accepted theories, but observationally it is always the case that they are identical to the limits of measurement. It is a good thing too as the exact correspondence between gravitational and inertial mass makes a lot of things like having stable orbits work. If you were to increase gravity by increasing gravitational mass and not inertial mass, suddenly things like angular momentum and stable orbits get all sorts of wonky. It is hard to say if solar systems are even possible in such a case.

All in all, it is a bad idea. Unless you are an energy being that really wants the universe to end in a Big Crunch instead of a Big Chill in which case crank up that constant, but expect biological life to take exception.

Comment: Great answer! And welcome to the site! But just so you know, we generally want answers to have a little evidence backing them up. We allow you to even cite Wikipedia (gasp) on this site. But we do appreciate something, or are these just speculations? Anyway, glad to have you here!

Comment: It is mostly fermi estimation, but the numbers are so huge, a few orders of magnitude it isn't going to change things much. :) 

calculating gravitational energy: http://burro.astr.cwru.edu/Academics/Astr221/StarPhys/gravity.html

confirmed with entries here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)

reference on different types of mass http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass

I think i am underestimating the damage caused to stars actually, so was very conservative in saying there would "just" be supernovas :)

Comment: You care right, I was considering the effects on planets and orbits but not on the internals of stars. It would need some pretty heavy simulations to model that but you're right that the results could be extremely dramatic. (although less dramatic results are also possible)

Comment: I am not sure why this superior answer is criticized for lack of evidence when accepted answer does not provide any.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I agree that this answer raised an extremely important point that mine had not considered. However stronger claims require stronger evidence. Most buildings on earth have extra strength designed in, the effect on the orbits is fairly easy to visualise. The effect on a star though is much harder to anticipate and a claim as strong as instant nova needs backing up in some way.

Comment: A comment on the second-to-last paragraph: there's no reason an increase in the strength of gravity needs to imply a change in gravitational mass, if you change the [gravitational constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) this will increase the gravitational force between two bodies even if their masses and the distance between them is held constant.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you think the Sun needs to immediately "shed" the gain in potential--wouldn't the larger potential just increase the pressure at the core, which would increase the rate of fusion and hence increase the radiation pressure until a new equilibrium was reached? After all there are plenty of stable stars whose potential energy is on the order of 2% larger than the Sun's.

Comment: @Hypnosifl because all the matter has to 'fall' into its new position and that kinetic energy doesn't go away just because the final configuration is theoretically stable. Think about it this way, there are  stable eggs on my shelf and there can be stable eggs sitting on the ground, but that doesn't mean I can roll an egg off my shelf and let it fall to the ground without consequences.

Comment: But what are you saying the "consequences" would be in the case of increasing the gravitational constant, analogous to breaking an egg? I assume you were talking about the idea that an unbroken egg on the ground and a broken egg on the ground are both stable configurations, but only one is likely to result from dropping an unbroken egg from a high shelf--are you saying there's an analogous case for a star, where we can think of two possible final stable configurations with the same number of particles & energy, but only one is likely to result from starting with a larger star and raising G?

Comment: Because the star would not have the same amount of energy, stable stars 2% bigger than the sun get their heat from nuclear fusion and it balances against gravity to form a stable size. By increasing G by 2% you add a ton of heat to the system due to pressure, about 10,000 times the total yearly output of the star. It is that extra energy that causes havoc  before the star has a chance to ever reach equilibrium.  Sort of like the extra energy from an egg falling off a shelf destroys the egg before it ever has a chance to become an intact egg sitting safely on the ground.