# What exactly would happen if a black hole was introduced into the sun?

Tags: science-based, black-holes

A ship powered by a [black hole of a few hundred thousand tons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_starship#Criteria) (say, under $6 \times10^8$ kg, which would have a lifetime of several years and a power output of a few hundred petawatts) crashes (malfunctions or is piloted deliberately, it doesn't matter) into the sun. The heat destroys the hull and exposes the black hole to the interior of the sun. What precisely would happen and on what kind of timescales?

Obviously, the sun would fall into the black hole, heating up and giving out huge amounts of radiation in the process. But how much radiation? How long would it be before effects were noticeable from orbit (eg from the Earth), and what would the effects be? How long would it take for the sun to be completely consumed? How would the radiation given off vary (roughly) over this time period? What would happen to the solar system throughout this process?

I'm looking for a timeline with (rough) details of the process and how it would develop. [This question is similar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/how-long-until-a-small-black-hole-makes-the-sun-fail) but the only answer with any details only calculates time to failure of the sun, and the answerer mentions that he seems to have made a mistake in his calculation, so it isn't a duplicate because it doesn't give the information I'm looking for.

Comment: How is it obvious? The _Earth_ has a mass of ~$6 \times 10^{24}$ kg. The black hole would be torn apart by the sun which wouldn't even register such a puny mass in its gravity well.

Comment: @nzaman By definition you can't "tear apart" a black hole. Nothing can leave the event horizon.

Comment: I recently proposed this sun/hole maneuver as a downvote hungry method of destroying a black hole on an idea here.  I asked exactly this question on the astronomy stack.  http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/can-a-black-hole-turn-back-into-a-star  The answer: black hole always wins.

Comment: @TimB: Hawking radiation does. Symmetry would imply a sufficiently large mass should be able to speed up the process. The only reason black holes exist is that they're the biggest bullies on their playground. An BH 16 orders of magnitude less than the Earth going against the Sun? It won't last

Comment: @nzaman It doesn't matter how big a block of cheese is. A knife will still cut it.

Comment: It seems likely that the black hole will start absorbing mass from the star, initially at the speed of sound for stellar medium (faster at the leading edge of the "falling" hole. Later the stuff being eaten will start spinning as it approaches the hole but either way that hole's going to be having a feast and getting fatter.

Comment: @TimB: Well, bearing in mind this is strictly theoretical physics, and we can never be sure of the outcome short of actually dropping a BH into the sun, here's my assessment. Assuming the BH is in Sol's gravity well, conservation of momentum means the BH will accelerate towards the sun faster than vice versa. Some H-atoms will fly directly into the BH, as it approaches, but so will the EM radiation of Sol, which will be significantly greater. As a result, the BH will no longer be an inert gravity well, but expand. But, as you stated, nothing escapes the event horizon, so what will happen is...

Comment: ...the blackbody radiation level will increase, as the amount of energy inside the BH increases, until it loses energy at the same rate as it gains it. At this point, it will be indistinguishable from the rest of the Sun, and is effectively no longer a black hole. Given the energy output of the Sun is ~$10^{25}$ J per second and an ~$6 \times 10^8$ kg mass, if wholly converted to energy gives approximately that much, the BH won't last more than a few seconds

Comment: @nzaman Black holes lose mass by Hawking radiation; blackbody radiation equivalent to a temperature _inversely_ proportional to the BH mass (it gets colder as it gets bigger). The blackbody radiation level will _decrease_, not increase, as more mass falls into the black hole. Power output falls with mass

Comment: This is answered over in Physics.SE. ["Throwing a micro black hole into the sun: does it collapse into a black hole or does it result in a supernova?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190308/throwing-a-micro-black-hole-into-the-sun-does-it-collapse-into-a-black-hole-or)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using your black hole from the actual size would be much smaller than a proton so it would have difficulty accreting mass because its effective cross section is very small. It may even only be able to absorb neutrinos, electrons, and gamma rays. Also, its overall gravity would still be very weak. It weighs as much as a building and you don't see people being drawn to buildings; at least until you get very very close to the singularity itself. Then there is the outpouring of [Hawking Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) as it evaporates which would certainly make it very difficult for mass to get close to it and would likely destructively interfere with any light trying to get in.

The black hole could probably fall all the way through the sun because its outpouring of radiation would clear a path for it. If it somehow got caught in the core of the star it may be unable to accrete mass for reasons previously mentioned, except by catching neutrinos. In the end, I suspect nothing much would happen.

---

**Math to support my claims and edited for clarity**

The black hole in question would be tiny, meaning that its Event horizon or Schwarzschild Radius is small. Knowing its mass we can calculate its size using [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/blkhol.html). The equation is:

$R_s = \frac{2MG}{c^2}$

Where:

$R_s$ is the Schwarzschild Radius

$M$ is the mass of the black Hole

$G$ is the universal gravitational constant

Plugging it all in:

$\frac{2\times6*10^{8}kg\times6.67*10^{-11}m^3 kg^{-1} s^{-2}}{(3*10^8m/s)^2}$

Gives a radius of

$R_s=8.91\times10^{-19} m$

For comparison the [radius of a proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_radius_puzzle) is around $8.5\times10^{-16}$. So its rate of accretion, if any at all would be very low.

Because of its low mass (relatively), its gravity won't be very strong at all. Using [Newton's Law of Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation):

$F=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$

Dividing by $M_2$ so we can get the acceleration due to gravity.

$a_g = \frac{GM_{1}}{r^2}$

Now we plug in the mass of the black hole and a few distances 10, 1, .1, .01, .001 meters to see what the acceleration due to gravity would be.

At 10 m the acceleration is $4\times10^{-4}m/s^2$

At 1 m the acceleration is $4\times10^{-2}m/s^2$

At .1 m the acceleration is $4m/s^2$

At .01 m the acceleration is $4\times10^{2}m/s^2$

At .001 m the acceleration is $4\times10^{4}m/s^2$

So even if it was a meter away from you would probably not notice it was there at all. Reaching out to it would end badly for you, but its sphere of influence is rather small.

Now there is the outpouring of radiation from the tiny singularity that would keep all matter far away from it because of the [pressure the radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure) exerts. First, we need to calculate the power being radiated from the black hole using the Stefan–Boltzmann–Schwarzschild–Hawking power law (really that's its name)

$P_b=\frac{\hbar c^6}{15360\pi G^2 M^2}$

where $\hbar$ is the [Reduced Plank Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant)

Plugging in our values we get a power output of

$P_b=9.89\times10^{14}$ watts

Now knowing the power output we can calculate the pressure exerted by the radiation using the planer Radiation Pressure Equation with the assumption of being normal to the surface we get:

$P_{rad}=\frac{E_f}{c}$

Where:

$E_f$ is energy flux in $w/m^2$

$c$ is the speed of light

$P_{rad}$ is pressure exerted by the radiation

In order to see if the out flowing of radiation would be enough to keep matter away even if the black hole passed through the core of the star, we are going to solve for the distance that the radiation pressure is equal to the [pressure in the core of the sun](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html). If that distance is less than the radius of the event horizon then matter will fall into the black hole, if it is larger then no matter will fall in. I am also assuming that the radiation is emitted from the black hole evenly in all direction, which may not be the case if the black hole has a large charge or is spinning rapidly. So we will solve:

$P_{sun} = P_{rad}$

Expanding

$P_{sun}=\frac{E_f}{c}$

Expanding a little more

$P_{sun}=\frac{\frac{P_b}{4\pi r^2}}{c}$

Where:

$P_{sun} =2.4*10^{16} Pa$

Plugging in our values and solving for $r$ we get:

$r=3.3\times10^{-6}m$

Meaning that the pressure from outflow of radiation will be equal to the pressure from the core of the star at that distance, which is much greater than the Schwarzschild radius. Therefore no matter will even be able to reach the singularity. I also suspect that the heating resulting from the outpouring of radiation would cause some expansion, but given the overall size of the sun it would be insignificant and would still find some kind of equilibrium.

Comment: Yes: the black hole would establish some kind of orbit through the sun's path the same way any object would, except it would fling itself through the sun without being destroyed a few times. It wouldn't just stop when it hits the sun's center, it would probably be flung straight through the sun, and then head into a very, very unstable orbit.

Comment: Cf. a similar fictional scenario in Larry Niven's short story *[The Hole Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hole_Man)* where instead of the Sun it is Mars that gets a nano-sized black hole. IIRC the main character guesstimates that nothing will happen for a long time.

Comment: It would even probably end oscillating, falling through the sun several times (Or hundreds of times) until it evaporated or somehow managed to experience drag. I think a nanoscale back hole would be much more dangerous. It's orders of magnitude larger (mass and actual size) and has less hawking radiation pouring out of it. That's a weird thing to say: nanoscale and orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: Will add an edit to see if the radiation pressure from the black hole is enough to really keep the matter away from it in the core of the sun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55770/discussion-between-joe-kissling-and-kingledion).

Comment: "ration pressure" -> "radiation pressure"?

Comment: There is another fictional scenario in *Earth* by David Brin, where Earth gets not one, but two microscopic black holes inside it. They start "orbiting" inside the planet.

Comment: Is the movement of the black hole through the sun relevant to the discussion of mass accretion?  A stationary black hole might hold off the star through radiation pressure, but when it is moving, mightn't it collide with bits of star stuff before they can get out of the way?  All it needs to do is accrue as much matter as it loses over time to stay stable forever.

Comment: @papidave Good question, but given its small size and the sheer magnitude of outpouring radiation I don't think speed is going to help it any at all.

Comment: Thank you - excellent point about the size and radiation pressure! But I am a little puzzled by a discrepancy in your calculation compared to values given in the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1803.pdf) mentioned in the link in the question. The authors used 6.06e8kg, and got very similar answers to you for radius, but their power calculation is 1.6e17 W - three orders of magnitude above yours - any idea why?

Comment: @Tharaib thanks for posting this link! I was looking for something like this. There is a discrepancy because the equation that I used is an approximation for black holes that are much larger than the one cited in the question. An larger black hole is much cooler so temperature dependent effects are negligible, this tiny black hole actually has such an extreme temperature that these dependent effects are very prominent. They accounted for them and I did not.

Comment: @JoeKissling I see! Thanks very much for the answer - I'll leave the question open a little longer just in case someone else has information to contribute, and then I'll accept your answer